# R Calculating Parametrical Expected Shortfall Values using the cvar package

Tags: r, statistics

I would like to calculate the Expected Shortfall (aka Conditional Value at Risk) using a parametric approach in R. One way of doing this is to code a custom function for each distribution which calculate the Expected Shortfall in a "closed form", for various distributions (e.g., Normal, Student's T and Lognormal).

I Stumbled across the cvar package and this provides functionality of calculating the expected shortfall using the normal "p,q" distribution name syntax in R, whilst providing the specific parameters as additional arguments. After back testing this package I get different answers relative to my own function and the QRM package's ES function for a normal distribution. Please help me to debug the potential issue.

Code below:

```
calculate_expected_shortfall <- function(mean, sigma, alpha) {
  # Calculate the z-score corresponding to the alpha level
  z_alpha <- qnorm(alpha)
  
  # Calculate the standard normal CDF value at z_alpha
  phi_z_alpha <- dnorm(z_alpha)
  
  # Calculate Expected Shortfall using the formula
  es <- mean + sigma * (phi_z_alpha / (1 - alpha))
  
  return(es)
}

# Example usage
mean <- 100   # Mean of the normal distribution
sigma <- 15   # Standard deviation of the normal distribution
alpha <- 0.95 # Significance level

# Method 1: Using the custom function
es_custom <- calculate_expected_shortfall(mean, sigma, alpha)

# Method 2: Using the QRM package
library(QRM)
es_qrm <- ESnorm(0.95, mu = mean, sd = sigma)

# Method 3: Using the cvar package
library(cvar)
es_cvar <- ES(pnorm, dist.type = "cdf", p_loss = 0.05, mean = mean, sd = sigma)
```

I tried reconciling the cvar package with results of custom function and QRM package's function. The expectation is that the result should be the same regardless of the method used.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot check the `QRM` package right now but `cvar` vs. a custom function I am able to do.
When I take the formula for the expected shortfall for the payoff of a portfolio from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall) it comes out as:

```
calculate_expected_shortfall <- function(mean, sigma, alpha) {
  # Calculate Expected Shortfall using the formula
  es <- -mean + sigma * (dnorm(qnorm(alpha)) / alpha)
  return(es)
}
```

If I compare this to cvar using the **same** parameters it gives the same results

```
# Example usage
mean <- 100   # Mean of the normal distribution
sigma <- 15   # Standard deviation of the normal distribution
alpha <- 0.95 # Significance level
library(cvar)
ES(qnorm, dist.type = "qf", p_loss = 0.95, mean = mean, sd = sigma) #-98.37154
calculate_expected_shortfall(mean, sigma, alpha) #-98.37154
```

Answer (score 0):

`QRM` estimates the Expected Shortfall differently than I have seen in most other calculations, including the wikipedia page shared in the answer above.

From the [package](https://github.com/cran/QRM/blob/master/R/Utility.R), this is their function:

```
##
ESnorm <- function(p, mu = 0, sd = 1){
  mu + sd * dnorm(qnorm(p)) / (1 - p)
}
```

The use of `(1-p)` in the denominator is different and likely what is causing the differences between `cvar::ES` and `QRM::ESnorm`